# Messages appear twice in outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I get all incoming messages twice in my outlook 2007, i have redirected my two different e-mail accounts to outlook 2007, when any message comes to the respective e-mails i get them twice in outlook 2007.

Any ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Who are the e-mail providers where you're redirecting mail from? Perhaps they should be contacted (i.e. it might be their fault you're getting dupes).

Comment: Its Gmail, its the problem with the Gmail then?

Comment: I don't know that it's a _problem_ with GMail, but it may be the settings you're using. Are you only redirecting the e-mails at one point (i.e. for one of the accounts, do you redirect to an "endpoint" or does the box you're redirecting to also redirect)?

Answer (score 1):

You said you have two different email accounts, I don't suppose you have one forwarding the messages to another?

If this is the case, as far as Outlook is concerned, they are two separate messages.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the options that could solve your issue:

- Go to advanced and remove leave message to server.
- Verify rules.
- Recreate the account.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the e-mails aren't being sent to both accounts?

If they are then, as you're collecting e-mails to both accounts in Outlook, you will get two copies of the e-mail.

Comment: No.. NO.. different messages comes to different e-mail accounts... no e-mail messages match each other, if i get any message to my x@gmail.com it appears twice, even if get the same message in y@gmail.com it appears twice in my outlook so it appears 4 times if its the same message that has been sent to different E-mail accounts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at whether the accounts in Outlook are set up as IMAP or POP accounts. I do not remember the exact details but I had a similar duplicates problem and the culprit was that the account type was set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things can cause this. To name a few:

- Incorrect Rules
- Multiple accounts configured incorrectly
- Profile recreation
- Email Synchronization tools
- Virus scanner/firewall configuration

This article on [Duplicate E-mails](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/duplicates.htm) covers each area in depth.